# Conditional Check for IPTables

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, iptables

I am trying to check whether specific rules in IPTables exists or not.

```
#!/bin/bash

if iptables -L -n | grep -- "ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8880";
 then
     echo "ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8880 exists"
 else
     echo "ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8880 does not exist"
fi

if iptables -L -n | grep -- "ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80";
 then
     echo "ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 exists"
 else
     echo "ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 does not exist"
fi
```

I am checking below two rules:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8880

ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80
```

Because those two rules already exists and conditions run the `TRUE` case, terminal also outputs the result of the `grep` in conditional check unnecessarily. `grep` somehow does not output for `FALSE` case.

How can I prevent the grep to output for `TRUE` case?

And how can I combine those separate two if conditionals into a single `OR` conditional?

BTW, my IPTables is old version and can not use `-C` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default action of `grep` is to print the matching line. To suppress that, you can use `grep -q`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if iptables -L -n | grep -q -- "ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8880";
 then
     echo "ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8880 exists"
 else
     echo "ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8880 does not exist"
fi

if iptables -L -n | grep -q -- "ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80";
 then
     echo "ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 exists"
 else
     echo "ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 does not exist"
fi
```

You could also simplify your script to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

rules=( "ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8880"  "ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80")


for rule in "${rules[@]}"
do
    iptables -L -n | grep -q "$rule" && echo "$rule exists" || echo "$rule does not exist"
done
```

Or, if you want to have multiple actions, use an if/else like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

rules=( "ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8880"  "ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80")


for rule in "${rules[@]}"
do
    if iptables -L -n | grep -q "$rule"
    then
        echo "$rule exists"
    else
        echo "$rule does not exist"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks @terdon, I will accept your question. Would you mind posting the code for "If one (or both) of these rules does not exist, echo the non-existent rule and do something"? I am trying to to check if there http rules exist or not, if not I will try to reload the iptables into default state. So it would be great to have double conditional but one block code to execute.

Comment: @NecNecco what do you mean? Both of the scripts above echo the rule and "does not exist" when the rule isn't present.

Comment: I mean if one of there rules does not exist or both of these rules does not exist, print the rule and reload the firewall. Currently `for` iterates two times. I am not sure where to put the code for firewall reloading. Sorry, new to bash scripting. I think just checking two rules with an `OR` and executing code in `then` section would do good.

Comment: @NecNecco see updated answer. Add the firewall code on a new line under the relevant `echo`.